# 18.04 NVIDIA drivers repeatedly uninstalls in dual boot system after running Windows

Tags: dual-boot, gpu, nvidia-geforce, timezone

I have a really weird situation on a dual boot (Windows 10 & Ubuntu 18.04) system.

Sometimes when I make changes in Windows then return to Ubuntu, I find the graphic card (a Titan GTX) is uninstalled in Ubuntu, resulting in ugly looking huge icons. This has happened multiple times, requiring multiple NVIDIA driver reinstalls iin Ubuntu.

The only thing that Windows and Ubuntu shares is system time (which, weirdly again, cannot be set in Ubuntu correctly via automatic option in settings).

How may I troubleshoot this to resolve this annoying problem?

Comment: Do you have secure boot enabled or disabled?

Comment: Should I do something to it?

Comment: It's been a long time since I had a dual boot system, but ISTR I struggled with it until I disabled secure boot.

Comment: It is already disable in my Windows.

Comment: Ok, then that isn't the problem :(

Comment: Give me an example of what kind of changes in Windows triggers this problem? And, to check the less obvious clue first... why can't you set the correct time in Ubuntu? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: What version driver for your video card?

Comment: @heynnema, Hi there! Thanks for reply; Regarding to the first question of yours (what kind of changes), for example when I install/uninstall some libraries like OpenGL, Qt, or even changing the versions in/uninstalling a specific compiler in Visual studio in Windoes, it can cause the problem. The output of nvidia-smi command "Driver Version: 430.40 ", CUDA Version: 10.1. And I don't know why I cannot change the system time. I set it manually for some time, but then I thought it may cause the problem.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks anyway:)

Comment: @fouroughgharbalchi 1) do you have any Windows drivers installed that allow you to read/write to Linux partitions? 2) do you have any (ntfs) partitions mounted in both OS's? 3) In Ubuntu, system time should be set automagically from the network... if there's a time discrepancy between Windows and Ubuntu time, there's a quick fix for that. 4) There's probably a newer Nvidia driver for your card. Check at https://www.geforce.com/drivers